# What transistor should I use? And how do I determine that?

Tags: transistors

Im new to designing a circuits. I've got my basic design done. I'm now trying to get to specific parts but I don't know which ones to buy. mainly because I don't know how to determine what I need. I'm hoping to use an NPN transistor as a switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUFLD4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What part should I buy and why. Could you take me through the process of determining the part?

Comment: Well, there's not much right about the diagram. However, it does express the fact that you want to switch 24 V, you want to use an NPN, and that there is a solenoid involved. We do not know what solenoid, or what's going to be driving/operating the switch, or how often it will be operated, or for what duration, or a lot of other things that would be useful to know -- ***especially*** when being asked to recommend "what part" to buy or how to figure it out. No one wants to write a curriculum. Could you help out by providing all of the associated details we would need to know to help you?

Comment: Im designing a circuit for a diy paper rocker launcher. The solenoid is from a sprinkler valve. and i would want this on until the system is charged with air. which i will be determining with a pressure switch that will turn off the signal to the base. I don't think it will be on for too long (max a second or two every 20 seconds or so).

Comment: We need to know how much current the transistor needs to pass, and we need to know what you'll be driving the base of the transistor with.  If you measure the resistance of the solenoid we can help you calculate the current (or if the solenoid coil is rated as requiring a certain current at 24V, that'll certainly tell us!)

Comment: I corrected the schematic so it would be a rational design to discuss.

Comment: R1 could be 4.7K and Q1 could be a MJE180. Lots of options here

Comment: why did you add the diode? @Sparky256

Comment: As you will learn it is mandatory to have a back-emf clamp diode at any solenoid or electromagnet. Not an issue when T1 is ON, but when switched OFF the stored magnetic field collapses back into the windings to produce the same current as was driving the coil. It is reverse voltage so it would damage the transistor unless it is clamped. Fancy way of saying the back-emf is shorted out before it can damage anything. Same thing applies to motors or any inductor with a large inductive value.

Comment: Correction. The voltage is not reversed when T1 is switched off, but the back emf induces current in the windings in the same direction, but with T1 OFF it has no place to go, so it will build up hundreds or thousands of volts until it finds a discharge path. The diode provides that path right at the coil.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments there is rather important information missing to give an accurate answer to the "what". But here are some steps you can take to come up with a possible solution yourself and then come back with a more specific question like "will transistor xyz fit my application".

1. Figure out what kind of transistor you want to use in term of NPN or
   PNP (maybe even a Mosfet?)
2. Determine the current your transistor has
   to be capable to draw
3. Determine to voltage the transistor has to withstand
4. Define the maximum power loss you can have in your transistor,
   consider switching losses if you have a fast switching application.
5. Open the search mask of a big distributor like mouser and try to find a transistor that meets the given criteria.
6. Check the datasheet for other parameters that might influence your design, if you need further help just come back with specific questions.

Comment: i will do a bit more research and come back with my findings. thanks guys!